# Code Not Printing In Async Python Websocket

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, websocket

I have been trying to build the following websocket using python:

```
import socket
import websockets
import asyncio
import traceback

# Find host name
HELLO_MY_NAME_IS = socket.gethostname()
print(HELLO_MY_NAME_IS)

# Find IP
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
    s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53))
    MY_IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    
print(MY_IP)

  async def port_scan():
    if not MY_IP[:3] == '192' and not MY_IP[:3] == '10.' and not MY_IP[:3] == '172':
        print('This is not a private network! SHUTTING DOWN!')
        exit()
    
    ip_range = MY_IP.split('.')
    ip_range.pop()
    ip_range = '.'.join(ip_range)
    print(ip_range)
      

async def register_client(websocket, _):
    async for message in websocket:
        print(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server = websockets.serve(register_client, MY_IP, 1111)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Everything seems to work fine and no errors come up. However, when I run the program, print(ip_range) does not show, which lies within 'async def port_scan()'. I think there is an issue with the code in this section. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: I think your snippet is missing some crucial lines, as I can't see you call (use) `port_scan` anywhere in it.

Comment: Right - that could be the issue. I can't believe I missed this! Thank you for your help, I will try this now and see if it works for me.